# A step I want to understand in solving this system of equations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

My question is about a step in my solution to this system of equations. 
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
a+b+c=0 \\ 
a^3+b^3+c^3 = 90\\ 
a^7+b^7+c^7 = 75810
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
**My solution:**
\begin{eqnarray*}
\because a+b+c = 0 \\
\therefore a^3+b^3+c^3 = 3abc, abc = 30 \\
a^7+b^7+c^7 = -7ab(a+b)(a^2+ab+b^2)^2 = 7abc(a^2+ab+b^2)^2 \\
\therefore (a^2+ab+b^2)^2 = 361 \\
a^2+ab+b^2 = \pm 19 \\
a^3 + a^2b + b^2a = 19a \\
a^3 + ab(a+b) = 19a \\
a^3 -19a -30 = 0 \\
(a-5)(a+3)(a+2) = 0, a \in \{5,-3,-2\}
\end{eqnarray*}$

Now I considered the case when $a^2+ab+b^2 = 19$, It provided the right answer to the system, yet when considering the negative case ($a^2+ab+b^2 = -19$), It doesn't provide the right answer when solving the cubic equation formed after multiplying by $a$. Why does this happen?

Comment: For real $a$ and $b$, $a^2+ab+b^2=(a+\frac b2)^2+\frac34b^2>0$

Comment: Ok, I got it now, thanks.

Comment: technically I should have said $\color{red}\ge0$ in my comment above

Comment: Your working is wrong at some stage

Comment: Can you be more clear about what did I do wrong? Because your work seems similar to mine.

Answer (score 1):

$a+b+c = 0$

$a^3+b^3+c^3 = 90$

$a^7+b^7+c^7 = 75810$

Clearly we can easily conclude that $c = -a-b$

$a^3+b^3+c^3 = (a+b+c)^3-3*(a+b)*(a+c)*(b+c)$

$90 = -3*(a+b)*(a+c)*(b+c)$

substitute that $c = -a-b$

$90 = -3*a*b*(a+b)$

Therefore $a*b*(a+b) = -30$

$a^7+b^7+c^7 = (a+b+c)^7-7*(b+c)*(a+c)*(a+b)*(a^4+2*a^3*b+2*a^3*c+3*a^2*b^2+5*a^2*b*c+3*a^2*c^2+2*a*b^3+5*a*b^2*c+5*a*b*c^2+2*a*c^3+b^4+2*b^3*c+3*b^2*c^2+2*b*c^3+c^4)$

substitute that $c = -a-b$

$a^7+b^7+c^7 = -7*b*a*(a+b)*(a^2+a*b+b^2)^2$

$75810 = -7×-30*(a^2+a*b+b^2)^2$

$361 = (a^2+a*b+b^2)^2$

Now $a^2+a*b+b^2 = \sqrt(361)$

$a^2+a*b+b^2 = ±19$

But only the positive value will work

Proof:

Since $a+b+c = 0$, then either $a$ or $b$ or $c$ must be negative, they can't be all positive.
Since we saw that $a*b*(a+b) = -30$
It means clearly that either $a$ or $b$ must be negative

$a^2+a*b+b^2 = \sqrt(361)$

$(a+b)^2-2*a*b+a*b = \sqrt(361)$

$(a+b)^2-a*b = \sqrt(361)$

Since we've proved that either $a$ or $b$ must be negative, and we know that the square of any number is always positive
( Checking )
$(positive) - (negative)$ must be $(positive)$

$a^2+a*b+b^2 = 19$

$a^3+a^2*b+a*b^2 = 19*a$

$a^3+a*b(a+b) = 19*a$

$a^3-30 = 19*a$

$a^3-19*a-30 = 0$

Which factors to
$(a-5)*(a+2)*(a+3)$

notice that a and b are symmetry in all the equations, therefore they will satisfy the same polynomial.
So the equation for b would also factor to $(b-5)*(b+2)*(b+3)$

The results of $a$ or $b$ or $c$ are $5$ or $-2$ or $-3$